# Combinations of a union type

Tags: typescript

I can generate combinations of unions that hold only property keys like this:

```
type KeyCombos<T extends PropertyKey> = {
  [K in T]: [K] | (KeyCombos<Exclude<T, K>> extends infer U extends any[] ? U extends U ? [K | U[number]] : never : never);
}[T];
```

and that is because mapped types only allow property keys. Here is some example usage of this type (wrapping in tuples so they don't get simplified into the original union):

```
type S = KeyCombos<"a" | "b" | "c">;
//   ^? ["a"] | ["b"] | ["c"] | ["b" | "c"] | ["a" | "b"] | ["a" | "c"] | ["a" | "b" | "c"]
type N = KeyCombos<1 | 2 | 3>;
//   ^? [1] | [2] | [3] | [2 | 3] | [1 | 2] | [1 | 3] | [1 | 2 | 3]
```

Now what I'd like to do is make this work for any kind of union. I thought I could use distributive conditionals, but either it's just not possible like this, or I'm using distributive conditionals incorrectly. Attempt 1 is show below:

```
type KeyCombos<T extends PropertyKey> = T extends T ? [T] | (KeyCombos<Exclude<T, T>> extends infer U extends any[] ? U extends U ? [T | U[number]] : never : never) : never
```

Obviously, `Exclude<T, T>` will be simplified to `never`, so this is not going to work. I get `["a"] | ["b"] | ["c"]` and `[1] | [2] | [3]` for the examples above, respectively. I thought I could just "copy" T and distribute over that and fix this. Attempt 2 now:

```
type KeyCombos<T extends PropertyKey> = T extends infer K ? K extends K ? [K] | (KeyCombos<Exclude<T, K>> extends infer U extends any[] ? U extends U ? [K | U[number]] : never : never) : never : never
```

but this results in the same results as attempt 1.

How can I make this work for any union? Note that I don't want permutations with tuples. That's pretty manageable and I have found answers for that. I have seen [Typescript string literal with permutations of union but no repetitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68030771/typescript-string-literal-with-permutations-of-union-but-no-repetitions) and [How to declare a type as all possible combination of a union type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703093/how-to-declare-a-type-as-all-possible-combination-of-a-union-type) but I got "scammed" in the latter question since the answer did not really make combinations :(

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NleYOm)

*P.S. If there was a question with an answer to this that flew under my radar, make sure to link it and I'll close this question as a duplicate*

*P.S.S. No, this isn't some gimmick for typings in a project. It's just having fun :)*

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252446/is-it-possible-to-generate-string-literal-combinations-with-template-literal-in#answer-68256789) you can find related question/answer. RElated, but not the same

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine Yeah I have seen that in my travels, but it is dealing with permutations. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using distributive conditionals is the right way. But as you noted, the `Exclude` is making problems. In both of your attempts, you are distributing over `T` which makes using `Exclude` with `T` useless. What you can do instead is copy `T` into an additional optional generic parameter `O` and then use `O` in the `Exclude`.

```
type KeyCombos<T, O = T> = 
  T extends infer U 
    ? [T] | (KeyCombos<Exclude<O, U>> extends infer U extends any[] 
               ? U extends U ? [T | U[number]] : never 
               : never)
    : never
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGED2BbARkgzgHgCoBooB5KAXilwD4yoBYAKCgqggA9gIA7AE0ygEtOAMwgAnKAFU6jJlAD8UANq4AulAA%20UABRxEqDDgCirAMYAbAK7cI2IoQmVqbDjz6CR4qc668oAQ04QRTUFL3YfPikFZQ1JRU4LdDEVNQAuKE4IADcxKHTMnNEASgZZPIzssQYGUEgoAGUaXWR0LGwAIj922Pa0bs12k3bKAG4GAHpx2QA9ORrwaAA5JvgWg2wARliAJliAZlGJqaZZ6vpJ-0DgAAtBAHMoG79gAUxOAHIXvygwUSRIUSgKAAd34ZjMUDQoggfgA1gA6REsHKcEH8G5QFAgKC7X7ZfhICx8Z4cFBgYCYeZ1EjkZr6NoAbygQiQSHSWwAvrEmWg-KJ0rsuZoeX4AF7pPZQDmHc7HKCzIA)