# Generate all possible boolean values in TypeScript type

Tags: typescript

I want to generate all possible values with given type.

```
type MagicGenerator<'withWishlist' | 'withAddToCart', PickerProps> = ??
```

So I expect that result of `MagicGenerator` would be as below:

```
type ExpectedResult =
  | ({
    withWishlist: true;
    withAddToCart: true;
  } & PickerProps)
  | ({
    withWishlist?: false;
    withAddToCart: true;
  } & PickerProps)
  | ({
    withWishlist: true;
    withAddToCart?: false;
  } & PickerProps)
  | ({
    withWishlist?: false;
    withAddToCart?: false;
  } & { [P in keyof PickerProps]?: never });
```

The main idea is that I want that the `PickerProps` will be `never` only if both of `withWishlist` and `withAddToCart` values is false or not provided

I tried to use something like this

```
type MagicGenerator<Keys extends string, Props extends object> =
  | ({ [K in Keys]: true } & Props)
  | ({ [K in Keys]?: false; } & {[P in Props]?: never})
```

but it gives me not full type

```
type NotFullResult = {
    withWishlist: true;
    withAddToCart: true;
    pickerProp: any
} | {
    withWishlist?: false | undefined;
    withAddToCart?: false | undefined;
    pickerProp?: undefined
}
```

Comment: How does this help you? The types are used only for compilation, they do not exist on runtime. They cannot protect you to get undesired values when the script runs. I would implement a validation in the code and move on.

Comment: @axiac Isn't it better if you can get a compile-time error instead of runtime? That's the whole point of TypeScript.

Comment: TypeScript prevents some coding errors but it cannot prevent errors that happen at runtime due to invalid data. Even if the values of `withWishlist` and `withAddToCart` always come from code and never from user input or database then TypeScript can prevent some errors but not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want

```
type MagicGenerator<Keys extends string, Props extends Object> =
  | ({ [K in Keys]?: boolean } & {[P in keyof Props]?: never})
  | ({ [K in Keys]?: false } & Props)
```

Demo: https://tsplay.dev/WP1PEw

Comment: Case 1 should be invalid, case 2 should be invalid, case 3 should be invalid, case 4 is valid, case 5 is valid. You've got them flipped.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow we need to get all the possible combinations of keys, and then set them to `true`. Luckily, I remember that I had asked about this [some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911435/combinations-of-a-union-type), so we could just reuse the types there:

```
type KeyCombos<T, O = T> = T extends infer U ? [T] | (KeyCombos<Exclude<O, U>> extends infer U extends any[] ? (U extends U ? [T | U[number]] : never) : never) : never;
```

Then, for each combination, we need to set the keys in the combination to `true` and the rest of the keys to `false` (and also make them optional). That can be done with a distributive conditional type and an intersection of two mapped types like this:

```
type MagicGenerator<Keys extends string, T, Combos extends string[] = KeyCombos<Keys>> =
    | ((Combos extends Combos ? { [K in Combos[number]]: true } & { [K in Exclude<Keys, Combos[number]>]?: false } : never) & T)
    | ({ [K in Keys]?: false } & { [K in keyof T]?: never }) extends infer O
    ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] }
    : never;
```

We also have to manually include the case where all keys are `false` or not provided, so that is what line 3 is for. Then, we use the classic `extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never` to "wrap up" and simplify the resulting type, so that it is displayed nicely in tooltips:

[image: tooltip]

Here's how you would use this generator:

```
type Props = MagicGenerator<"withWishlist" | "withAddToCart", PickerProps>;
```

where for testing purposes `PickerProps` is

```
interface PickerProps {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
    baz: boolean;
}
```

Note that this works even if you have more than two keys you want to use this for (for example, if you had another key, `withBookmarks`, it would still work). That is why it is complicated. If you *only* need it to work for two keys, you should probably just hardcode it.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArAQa2qqB7ABwGdkBvAKGSuRjzwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuS69uKIyJgooAOY9qyfgC9G7OgBsIcEDwC+5cmACeBFAGkIOgMJ4OeIgB4AKgBpkAeWQBeZDYB8r98ggAPSBAAExJQGGhkAFVkAH5kAG0bAF1kAB9kAAojU3MFawBRPwRFZiCIK0cHSI8vf0CQ5DCI6LqIYJJVHXiUuIyWgLaG6LjEtKj4lg5oJJTGEAgAN2gASmQ5xZW1pg2oHm09FABZODEMAHE26DgwPCgrbJJW9uRhURAxB3tkMwtHgefXuJut5sj88vdjEQaq5eFR0hkMmDLL5-g0kSQ4qQEgZGiBvrlLBM2JwoDNGCJmCh1MgAGRkbG45CFYqlcoPBzoolTUkeJIxRjwRREKlbeZLKCrOk2ZawsYZLHxHGgZAPPkCuBCkV0hVKvHYHR4GDuNXbcXIdSrJ4NJpQJyyzEM5X6w1OJKMRyKlKaKTrcV7XT6ND4YjeY6nBAXeZQa63KwAIgA7sAwAALADqwCIKcUmbAcbGieTKYAgkEgjY8CYBHmHOgsDhg1CeAB6ZvUAB6MS0MGYIAQYGAeDxkGEGQIjcYuEIRFWpE02ggo7ny39i7A8tlSdTpfLler5KglLs5Atq6Xm6LGazOeEB6PJ5XWhH64oUloDGQAAZj1J+IJkHGcY-nwcByDQGrCsBVBbiWZYVlWUBgHeEBQcgMFXtmubqpqx6nuQQA)

---

p.s. I don't believe this is the "cleanest" or "fastest". Someone will probably post a better solution later (or maybe I can optimize this one).